# How to sync files between 2 computers using homegroup connected via Ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel

I have two  computers connected via a crossover Ethernet cable using a homegroup. I can access a folder on  computer #1 from computer #2 and have set it up as read only. I want an Excel file on computer #2 to be in sync with computer  #1 when updates occur. Can someone recommend how to do that? The way I have to do it now is to close and re-open the  file on computer #2, which works fine but is cumbersome and I'd like another option.

Computer #1 is on Windows 10 and Computer #2 is on Windows 7

I will not have internet capabilities where I'll be working so cannot use the  cloud solution.

Thanks you

Comment: I vaguely remember newer versions of office were aware of this - what version of office?

Answer (score 0):

Changes will show when the file is opened. Any changes that happen to the file while it is open as read only on another machine won't show. There is no magic synchronization that works while the file is open. Only Excel Online can show changes by other users live, as they are happening. For a home office solution you will need to keep re-opening the file on computer #2 when it has been changed on computer #1.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score -1):

First, this won't be easy.

After you create a database in access, you can then configure both windows to connect to it via odbc.  Excel can do odbc.

You will have to modify your spreadsheet in a way that the outputted data is usefully displayed.

Here is 1 possible example

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-an-Access-database-to-your-workbook-a3d6500c-4bec-40ce-8cdf-fb4edb723525

You can then point, both copies of excel at the same database and/or table.

You may still have to press F5 to update the displayed data.